# Laravel use link table on model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I have the tables tags, posts and a link table for these
Now I want to get all the tags from the current post.

Now I want to get all the tags related to this post.

I made a model "Tag" (with no functions yet, just extending Eloquent)

How can I use this model to get all the tag names/titles based on the current post id, or do I need a seperate model for the Linking table(Which seems incorrect to me)?

I'm kinda lost in it right now, probably due to too much searching. 
Anyone can help me out here?

**SOLVED**

```
$post = Post::where('id', $id)->first(); 
$tags= $post->tags;
```

Tags function in the Post model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

Comment: Have you read up on Eloquent? This is explained in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following function to your `Post` model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

Now you can call `$post->tags()->getResults()` to get all tags of a post.

Corresponding docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks a lot
My end result that worked:
`$post = Post::where('id', $id)->first()
  $tags= $post->tags;`

Comment: Btw when I try using getResults() it says it doesn't exist.
Also I get all tags? So I get twice the fun tag and 1 time the Horror tag.

The current post has Fun and Horror tag, but I always get everything from the link table